# Xcode 6.4 Export Adhoc "Session has expired"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to export an iPhone app using Xcode 6.4 but am receiving an error:

> Your session has expired. Please log in.

When Xcode checks the developer portal for Development Teams.

I have double checked my credentials in `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts` and I am able to select "`View Details`" for the team and see Signing Identities and Provisioning Profiles as expected. I did try selecting the little refresh button in the bottom left and received the same error:

> Your session has expired. Please log in.

I double checked logging into the developer portal and no problems there.

I tried restarting Xcode and was able to select my Development Team, but right as the build started to export, Xcode crashes.

I did notice that Xcode 7.1 has been released. Maybe Xcode 6.4 is no longer supported?

**Edit**
Here's the stack trace from the crash:

```
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6E35b
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-7714/DVTFoundation/Portal/DVTDeveloperPortalDatabase.m:3277
Details:  (token.team) should not be nil.
Object:   <DVTListDevicesOperation>
Method:   +operationWithSingleTeamToken:andPlatform:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc67ef94900>{number = 43, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000105c86fda -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001049d765f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001049d794e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001048f63ba +[DVTTeamOperationBase operationWithSingleTeamToken:andPlatform:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000105f1a301 __75-[IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStepViewController _refreshDevicesFromPortal]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00000001048fedc9 __DVTOperationForBootstrappingTokenWithSingleTeamAndRunDependentOperationCreationBlock_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x000000010484adef -[DVTOperation main] (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x00000001048f339a -[DVTPortalOperation main] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x000000010487533c -[DVTOperationGroup start] (in DVTFoundation)
  9  0x00000001048f32e3 -[DVTPortalOperation start] (in DVTFoundation)
 10  0x00007fff90509613 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff92cabc13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff92caf365 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff92cb0ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff92cae6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff92cbcfe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff99b73a9d _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 17  0x00007fff99b713dd start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
((token.team)) != nil
```

Comment: The funny thing is it also happened to me 5 mins ago. I am using Xcode 7.0.1 by the way.

Comment: Same issue here. Yesteday worked OK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like Apple has some kind of technical issues today. It's not related to version of XCode. I see the same error with XCode 7.0.1 right now. Re-adding account will not help.

Comment: Same problem with xcode 7.1 (7B91b), I even tried two different developer accounts.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Along with these wonderful error messages: "The selected team doesn't have an iOS Developer Program membership" (I do), and "The account _ has no team with ID _" (it does). I've been pulling my hair out over this all morning.

Comment: Aaaaaand it's back working now. Didn't have to do anything.

Comment: Now it's working for me too, seemed to be some Apple problem.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue.  One of the accounts in Xcode (7.1) needed to be logged into again - not sure why.  In Xcode preferences, went through the accounts and one said to login. That fixed it.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Since I posted this question last week, Apple seemed to fix the problem. I am trying to submit an app today and the dreaded "Your session has expired.  Please log in" message came up again. Turns out one of my accounts (not even the one I needed) had its session expired... which I've never seen before.

Comment: As a side note, this seems to be a separate issue from the original. New occurrence though.

Comment: This was the problem for me too, One for profile's password was changed so had to re-enter it. It couldn't fetch the entire list so was showing at error

Answer (score 1):

Went to Xcode Preferences | Accounts and removed my AppleID then re added it.  That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

please login in Apple Developer account than check you ad-hoc certification if its expire then re-edit

Comment: Double checked those. I deleted certificates and provisioning profiles and re-added with no luck

Comment: I deleted the AdHoc provisioning profile and regenerated. No dice.

Answer (score 0):

my solution for this problem:
in xcode press Product/Archicve
In the appeared popup  press export, than select 'Save for Ad-hoc develoment' and press 'Next'. After tap 'View accounts...' . In the appeared window,  wait few seconds, when xcode shows symbol 'connection problem'. Than re-login all developer account

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the following - I have multiple accounts logged in in Xcode  accounts section. And there was a problem with only one of them (1 out of 6). The password was changed. So after re-logging in with that account that had the problem I was able to fix the issue.

The problem arises because Xcode tries to check all of the accounts before exporting the binary, and if there is a problem with one of them, you will not be able to proceed.

To check your accounts go to **Preferences -> Accounts**

Answer (score 0):

I know that is not a new question but if you have multiple accounts in your Xcode, this problem may be appeared if some of your accounts has changed its password.

Go to Preferences -> Accounts and check your accounts. If some of them has any problem, a sign of "Sign in" will appear next to its name

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. List item
2. Login to your apple developer account.
3. Go to "Certificates Identifiers & Profiles.
4. Find your Provisioning profile (Left-side menu: Provisioning profiles -> All)
5. Click on the corresponding profile in the list
6. Download the profile
7. Double-click on the downloaded file (Xcode will open it)

That's all