# xcode - your session has expired. please log in

Tags: ios, xcode

When I change my new Mac, this error showing for me, every time I have to type my password in Xcode -> performance -> Accounts. But after type my Apple developer password everything work fine. When I close Xcode and reopen, then it is still showing:

> Your session has expired. Please log in.

[image: Xcode Accounts screenshot]

How can I solve this problem? Previously I never needed to type the Apple developer password every time.

And I tried a lot of solutions already, but none are working for me:

- Changed my Apple develop account password
- Changed permission in Keychain to all access
- `DevToolsSecurity —status` ,`DevToolsSecurity --enable` in Terminal
- Restarted my mac

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445745/xcode-export-upload-error-your-session-has-expired-please-log-in

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I follow all answer did already, if solved I will not ask here, please

Comment: Yeah, me too. After I restart my Mac (or turn it off). It always auto logout all my account.

Comment: @QuocNguyen I also tried to restart my mac already, also not solved.

Comment: Apple's services seem to change frequently, which is frustrating. Something is invalidating your session. Additional information like version of Xcode would help. Also, have you tried deleting that profile then adding again?

Comment: @n8yn8 I update my detail into my question, please check, thank you

Comment: @n8yn8 and I tried adding again account in xcode already, but not working for me.. and I also think I got expire account, because I change two times mac and I have to make two different certificate

Comment: @YuyangHe, unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the problem you are having. The best I can offer is to post a question in Apple's developer forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my problem solved by update Xcode new version. It is Xcode issue and new version fixed already.

[image]

Before I am using version 9.3.0 that showing this kind of error.